# Show product image instead of product name on the "recently viewed" block

Tags: php, smarty, cs-cart

I'm using CS-Cart 4.1.x

I created an override for the block "design\themes\basic\templates\blocks\products\products_text_links.tpl"

The code that I see in the default file is:

```
{** block-description:text_links **}

<{if $block.properties.item_number == "Y"}ol{else}ul{/if} class="bullets-list">

{foreach from=$items item="product"}
{assign var="obj_id" value="`$block.block_id`000`$product.product_id`"}
{if $product}
    <li>
        <a href="{"products.view?product_id=`$product.product_id`"|fn_url}">{$product.product nofilter}</a>
    </li>
{/if}
{/foreach}

</{if $block.properties.item_number == "Y"}ol{else}ul{/if}>
```

What I need to do is just to replace the following line with the proper code to show the product's default image instead of its name:

```
{$product.product nofilter}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: AM not aware of Smarty or CS-Cart.. but, i cannot find any <img> tag here to display an image... You did not give any image tag, so i think its the problem why you can't view the image.. Sorry, if my answer is wrong.. Have a great day and Merry Christmas.. :-)

Comment: @annampriyatam right, but that's something I can add later. I just need to know the property/code that returns the image link. Thanks anyway and Merry Christmas.

Comment: Enable smarty debugging (with {debug}) and see how the products array looks like. There you should see where to find the URL to the image. Take a look at this doc: http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.1.x/api/entities/products.html#main-pair

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{foreach from=$items item="product"}
    {if $product}
        {assign var="obj_id" value="`$block.block_id`000`$product.product_id`"}
        {include file="common/image.tpl" image_width=$block.properties.thumbnail_width image_height=$block.properties.thumbnail_height obj_id=$obj_id images=$product.main_pair href="products.view?product_id=`$product.product_id`"|fn_url}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```